# pass an array from pug (jade) to jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, pug

I have a array `fields` which contain a list of strings:

```
var fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'zed'];
```

I pass it to pug from express like this:

```
app.get('/some_route', function(req, res) {

    res.render('some_view', { fields: fields });

});
```

Now I want to use that array inside jquery script,
I already try:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var fields = #{fields};
        // return: var fields = foo,bar,zed;
    });
</script>
```

and:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var fields = JSON.parse(#{fields});
        // return: var fields = JSON.parse(foo,bar,zed);
    });
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON-encode it an put it in an attribute somewhere, like on the `<script>` itself:

```
script(id='field-source', data-fields=JSON.stringify(fields)).
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var fields = JSON.parse($('#field-source').data('fields'));
    });
```

It’s possible to put it directly into the script with some careful escaping¹ (JSON-encoding is not enough!), but not worth the effort when attributes already work so reliably.

<sub>¹ You start by JSON-encoding, then make it safe for the JavaScript context by replacing U+2028 and U+2029 with `\u202[89]`, then make it safe for the HTML context by replacing `<` with `\x3c`. Replacing only `</` is not enough, as `<!--` can also mess with parsing in certain contrivable ways.</sub>

Comment: based on your answer this should work too: ` var fields = JSON.parse(#{JSON.stringify(customerFields)}) ` ?

Comment: I get this work by only add : ` var fields = !{JSON.stringify(customerFields)} `

Comment: @younel: That’s exactly what I said not to do. It’s an HTML injection (“XSS”) vulnerability.